# What does it mean the given behavior on my laptop?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

After updating my system and before, I got this issue but I don't understand why that happens sometimes.
By the way, The screen is not broken and the laptop is Acer aspire E5-527G-39m5
Maybe are not installed drivers for the NVIDIA video card or the Intel driver working not correctly?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you connect it to another monitor/screen does it have
the same problem ?.

If not then its just like the problem my colleague had  , turns out it was a hardware problem .Due to  continuous opening and closing of the lid , the cable that runs to the laptop monitor had been damaged.

Comment: It's fixed when I've logged in. And I noticed It"s happening after updating the system. So also, If there are no drivers for the Nvidia graphics card (but I don't use the laptop for gaming or something like that. and I use just an integrated Intel graphic card) my laptop will work correctly or I should install them for my machine???